# How to know in which thread widget are created in PySide6?

Tags: threadpool, qthread, pyside6

I am trying to implement multi-thread in a QT application developed with PySide6.
Starting from [this example](https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/multithreading-pyside6-applications-qthreadpool/) I have a code which looks like the code below.

The below code works well, without error. In my complete code, I got an error in the corresponding `add_item_tree` function. The error comes when I click (right click) on the new created item in the tree. The item is well created (as in my short example below) but after, if I click or interact with him I got the error.

I got the following error:

```
QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread
QObject::startTimer: Timers cannot be started from another thread
QObject::installEventFilter(): Cannot filter events for objects in a different thread.
QObject::installEventFilter(): Cannot filter events for objects in a different thread.
QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread
qt.qpa.window: Window position QRect(-4,42 283x401) outside any known screen, using primary screen
[1]    92579 segmentation fault
```

Is there a way to know, when I reach the `add_item_tree` function, which thread is running? The Tree widget and several items are created before. The object returned by the function executed through the worker does not create any widget. New widget are created in the `add_item_tree` function.

I don't know how to dig into this error ... The main goal, is to be able to add to my tree a new item from the object returned by the worker.

```py
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QPushButton, QWidget, 
                               QMainWindow, QApplication, QTreeWidget,
                               QTreeWidgetItem, QStackedWidget)
from PySide6.QtCore import QRunnable, Slot, Signal, QObject, QThreadPool, QThread

import sys
import time
import traceback

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.widgets import Cursor
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qtagg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qtagg import FigureCanvasQTAgg


class BasePlotter(FigureCanvasQTAgg):
    """ This class define base method for plotter classes """

    def __init__(self, my_object, a: float):
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
        super().__init__(self.fig)

        self.my_object = my_object
        self.a = a
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self)
        self.cursor = Cursor(self.ax, horizOn=True, vertOn=True,
                             useblit=True, color='black', linewidth=1)
        x = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
        self.ax.plot(x, self.a * x ** my_object.n)
        self.draw()

    def get_plot_widget(self, parent):
        plot_widget = QWidget(parent=parent)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(plot_widget)
        layout.addWidget(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)

        return plot_widget


class WorkerSignals(QObject):
    '''
    Defines the signals available from a running worker thread.
    '''
    started = Signal(str)
    finished = Signal(str)
    error = Signal(tuple)
    result = Signal(object)


class Worker(QRunnable):
    """
    This is a general class to run any threads.

    Inherits from QRunnable to handler worker thread setup, signals and wrap-up.

    """

    def __init__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Initialize the work with the function to run and its arguments

        Args:
            fn (function): the callback function to be run in the threads
            args: positional arguments to pass to the callback function
            kwargs: keywords arguments to pass to the callback function
        
        """
        super().__init__()

        # Store constructor arguments (re-used for processing)
        self.fn = fn
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.signals = WorkerSignals()

    def run(self):
        '''
        Initialise the runner function with passed args, kwargs.
        '''

        self.signals.started.emit(self.fn.__name__)

        # Retrieve args/kwargs here; and fire processing using them
        try:
            # execute the function and catch any errors
            # worker args and kwargs are passed to the function
            result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        except Exception:
            # get and return the error
            traceback.print_exc()
            exctype, value = sys.exc_info()[:2]
            self.signals.error.emit((exctype, value, traceback.format_exc()))
        else:
            # return the results in case of normal ends
            self.signals.result.emit(result)
        finally:
            # final worker signal
            self.signals.finished.emit("THREAD COMPLETE!")


class PlotItem(QTreeWidgetItem):
    
    def __init__(self, parent, plot, idx, name):
        super().__init__(parent, [f"{name}"])
        self.plot = plot
        self.idx = idx


class CustomItem(QTreeWidgetItem):
    
    def __init__(self, parent, my_object):
        super().__init__(parent, [f"Item {my_object.n}"])
        self.my_object = my_object

    @classmethod    
    def get_new_item(cls, tree, stack, my_object):
        # do more operations
        item = cls(tree, my_object)

        for ai in [0.01, 0.1]:
            plot = BasePlotter(my_object, ai)
            plot_widget = plot.get_plot_widget(stack)
            stack.addWidget(plot_widget)
            idx = stack.indexOf(plot_widget)
            pitem = PlotItem(item, plot, idx, f"plot {ai}")
            item.addChild(pitem)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"my object {self.my_object.n}"


class MyObject:

    counter = 0

    def __init__(self, n: int):
        self.n = n

    @classmethod
    def get_object(cls, n: int = None):
        print("get object thread: ", QThread.currentThread())
        time.sleep(2)
        cls.counter += 1
        return cls(cls.counter)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.tree = QTreeWidget()
        self.tree.setColumnCount(1)
        self.tree.setHeaderLabels(["counter"])
        button = QPushButton("Run!")
        button.pressed.connect(self.add_item)
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.plot_stack = QStackedWidget()

        item = CustomItem.get_new_item(self.tree, self.plot_stack, MyObject(0))
        self.tree.insertTopLevelItem(0, item)

        layout.addWidget(button)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.plot_stack)
        layout.addWidget(self.tree)

        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self.show()

        self.tree.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.handle_selected_item)

        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
        print("Multithreading with maximum %d threads" % self.threadpool.maxThreadCount())

    def handle_selected_item(self):
        item = self.tree.selectedItems()[0]
        self.label.setText(f"Item {str(item)}")
        if isinstance(item, PlotItem):
            self.plot_stack.setCurrentIndex(item.idx)

    # @Slot(object)
    def add_item_tree(self, my_object):
        print("add_item thread: ", QThread.currentThread())
        item = CustomItem.get_new_item(self.tree, self.plot_stack, my_object)
        self.tree.insertTopLevelItem(0, item)

    @Slot(str)
    def print_message(self, message):
        print(message)

    def add_item(self):
        # add item without threads
        # myo = MyObject.get_object()
        # self.add_item_tree(myo)

        # add item with threads
        worker = Worker(MyObject.get_object)
        worker.signals.started.connect(self.print_message)
        worker.signals.result.connect(self.add_item_tree)
        worker.signals.finished.connect(self.print_message)

        # Execute
        self.threadpool.start(worker)


print("Initial thread: ", QThread.currentThread())
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
app.exec()
```

**EDIT**

I edit the code to succeed to reproduce part of the error including more functionalities. As you may see, there are two type of TreeItem in the tree, data or plots, plots being children of data. From the app, you can make operations on the data to produce new data or new plots and finally add new item (or child) in the tree.

I say that I reproduce part of the error because here, I got a segmentation fault. Actually it depends if I set the `@Slot` on the `add_item_tree`. Moreover, the `finished` signal is never fired. The message is not printed.

```
$ > python --version
Python 3.9.18
$ > python mythreads2.py
PS: 6.5.2 QT: 6.5.2
Initial thread:  <PySide6.QtCore.QThread(0x600000024180) at 0x7fe8ac3b44c0>
Multithreading with maximum 8 threads
get object thread:  <PySide6.QtCore.QThread(0x600000ce9020, name = "Thread (pooled)") at 0x7fe8acc921c0>
get_object
add_item thread:  <PySide6.QtCore.QThread(0x600000024180) at 0x7fe8ac1d0900>
[1]    12306 segmentation fault  python mythreads2.py
$ > python -m pip freeze
PySide6==6.5.2
PySide6-Addons==6.5.2
PySide6-Essentials==6.5.2
```

Comment: You can use `print(QThread.currentThread())`, which in PySide will show the thread-id of the currently executing thread; and `print(object.thread())` to show the thread in which the qwidget/qobject lives. It will also help to execute the former statement before creating the app object so you know the thread-id of the main thread. Obviously, when the problem object is created, the current, main and object thread-ids *should* all be the same. But if they aren't, it may be due to how and/or when the signals are connected (although this is just an educated guess).

Comment: Note that the slot signature of `add_item_tree` is wrong: you're using `Slot(int)`, but the `result` signal is declared for `object`. PySide is particularly permissive about this (in PyQt this throws an exception), but you should be more careful about it anyway. In any case, I cannot reproduce this in PySide2 nor PyQt5/6, so it must be a PySide6 issue (I cannot test right now). Consider trying `worker.signals.result.connect(self.add_item_tree, Qt.ConnectionType.QueuedConnection)`.

Comment: Besides, the answer to the question of your title is: always in the main thread, or, to be precise, the thread in which QApplication lives, which is the only thread from which widgets can be created, including UI elements used by widgets (such as tree widget items). So, based on this, it's possible that for some reason `add_item_tree` is being called by the other thread, causing issues with the UI thread. All this is obviously based on the assumption that you can actually reproduce the issue with the code you provided us, and you don't do something else we know nothing about in the real code.

Comment: From my tests `add_item_tree` runs in the main threads. I edit the code to get one that produces an error.
I tried to change the `ConnectionType` but it does not fix the issue

Comment: @Ger The edited example does not behave in the way you describe. With or without the slot decorator, it does not raise any exceptions and the finished message is always printed. Are you ***absolutely certain*** that the code in the question is exactly the same as what you are testing? And how are you running it? You should always run test-code in a standard terminal, rather than an IDE. Please also state which platform you are testing on and show the output of `print('PS:', QtCore.__version__, 'QT:', QtCore.qVersion())`.

Comment: Thanks @ekhumoro. To be absolutly certain I copied the code from the question in a new file and run the file in a fresh directory out of the directory of my project (the only change is that I uncomment the line with @slot). The output is in the last edit of the question. I am on MacOS, I don't know if this matter. I previously ran the code from the terminal of VScode but as you have suggested I did it also from iterm and the standard MacOS terminal. In the standard terminal I had to click two times on the button to get the error but in both cases the final message isn't printed.

Comment: @Ger It's looking like a platform and/or version specific PySide6 bug. Try creating a PyQt6 port of the test-script to see if that behaves differently. I am only able to test on Linux, but I will try later using the same PySide6 version you are using (previously, I tested with version 6.6.1).

Comment: @Ger I tested using version 6.5.2 of PySide6 on Linux, and I can now reproduce the problem. Commenting out ***both*** Slot decorators prevents the segfault and also prints the finished message. Adding the line `worker.setAutoDelete(False)` also prevents the problem (with or without the Slot decorators). However, I don't like this as a solution, because adding `def __del__(self): print('del')` to the Worker class shows that it doesn't get deleted *at all* (so probably causes a memory leak). The correct solution is to upgrade PySide6 (ideally to 6.6.1, but other versions may also work).

Comment: @ekhumoro actually it looks like I cannot update to an higher PySide6 version than 6.5.2. `pip install` says `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PySide6>=6.6` I will try on windows instead of macos to know if it exists.